# where the createFormBuilder()?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2 and FOSUserBundle

I want to use 'createFormBuilder' in ProfileController

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\AttrMutor;


class ProfileController extends ContainerAware
{
      $attrMutor = new AttrMutor();
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($attrMutor);
```

it shows such as

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::createFormBuilder()
```

How can I solve this?

I can use $this->createFormBuilder in other Controller such as

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
      $attrMutor = new AttrMutor();
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($attrMutor);   //OK
```

I think there is a hint in differences between extends ContainerAware and extends Controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `createFormBuilder` method is in Symfony's base `Controller` class.
 (http://api.symfony.com/2.3/index.html?q=createFormBuilder)

If you only want to have your controller extend `ContainerAware` instead of `Controller`, you can still get the form builder from the service container:

```
$builder = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, $options);
```